# Baileys 4-step FFT without bit reverse sorting

Tags: algorithms

> I'm not really sure, if this is the right place to ask this question. I would have asked on stackoverflow, but since my question is rather theoretical, I ask here. When I'm wrong, please migrate. Thank you :)

I'm trying to multiply polynomials using FFT. When doing an FFT in-place, the output is in [bit-reverse order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation), which doesn't matter much, because when doing a convolution and an inverse FFT, the order will be reversed again.

I'm now trying to reduce memory bandwith using [Bailey's 4-step FFT](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/fftq.pdf). While a normal FFT reads the data as often as $k$ times when the size of the transform is $2^k$, the 4-step FFT does it only two times (not counting CPU cache access). I'm implementing it as follows:

1. Write my data as an $n_1 \times n_2$ matrix. Do $n_2$ in-place FFTs on the columns. Reorder the columns.
2. Do the multiplication with the roots of unity (see paper)
3. Do $n_1$ in-place FFTs on the rows, do not re-order the data, because it's not needed for the convolution to work.

However, when I omit the reordering in step 1, I'll get incorrect results.  The re-ordering requires significant additional resources. Is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: Reordering should take linear time, compare the the $n\log n$ complexity of the entire FFT algorithm. Perhaps you should optimize this part of your algorithm?

Comment: It is possible to eliminate reordering, if you can spare additional memory (it is not in-place anymore). But as already pointed it is the cheapest operation in FFT. The coefficients are real or complex?

Comment: When the polynomials are huge there are ways to do it more efficient: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00520207/document